# Manually changing coefficients of a model

Tags: logistic-regression, orange

Is there a way to manually change parameters of a model in Orange 3?

I have a dataset and trained a logistic regression model on it. Now, I can alter the coefficients (beta values) of the logistic regression model and visualize how it changes the predictions.

Is there a simple way to do that in Orange? I understand the model parameters will not be optimal if I am manually change them, but still is there a way to do it?

Thanks.